# prove the statement (big O notation)

Tags: asymptotics

Prove the following statements:

1. $2^n$ is $O(n!)$, and
2. $n!$ is not $O(2^n)$

not sure where to start with these two... thanks

Comment: Do you mean $n!$ is not $O(2^n)$?

Comment: ops, yes thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Note that $\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac{2\times 2 \times 2\cdots \times 2}{1\times 2 \times 3\times 4\cdots \times n} \le 2$ for all $n$.  Hence $|2^n| \le 2 |n!|$ for all $n$.
2. Suppose that there is an $M$ such that $|n!| \le M |2^n|$ for all $n$ (sufficiently large).   Try to find a contradiction.

Comment: i've checked 0, 0! <= M * 1 this holds

Comment: since M could be anything I chose shouldn't this always hold?

Comment: $M$ needs to be chosen, held fixed.  It needs to work for all $n$ (except possibly finitely many small ones).